# Ask for password every time i mount encrypted partition

Tags: macos, security, disk-encryption

So I created an encrypted partition on my main hard drive.

Mac OS X would ask for its password only when I would start the system. Then I unmount it, then I try to mount it again and OS X wouldn't ask for a password. Until i reboot again.

How do I make OS X ask for that password every damn time I (hopefully only I) try to mount that partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that [bug](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4937813) still hasn't been corrected in 10.9 (Mavericks).  The only workaround I have seen requires that to be on an external drive and you'd need to unplug it after unmounting.

Not ideal in the least:  I guess the only real "solution" is shut down before you take your computer on the move with you and have a concern about that or reboot after unmounting it.

Comment: Any way I can force it to forget the password from Terminal?

Comment: @KonstantinBodnya - Not that I have seen in the little research.  I use external drives for that stuff though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, you might be able to convert the partition into a disk image. That can be mounted from the terminal, and at least on my system, it requires the password every time (I've never clicked "save the password").

The key is to use the `-stdinpass` flag on creation and mounting of the disk image. Personally, I have the image on my already encrypted disk, and I mount it from the terminal when I want access, then unmount it as normal (right click, eject). I followed these instructions to set it up, with one exception, that I require the `-stdinpass` argument on mount as well as on creation:

http://rubenerd.com/mac-encrypted-disk-images/